# jquery slider stop sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two slider which are dependent from each other. Both slider have a range from 0 till 100. The slider is calculated by some other fields. So I can get on the slider one 99 and on the slider two 30. If I change the range of slider two, slider one become over 100, but it should stop slider two if slider one will get over 100. 
I have tried to stop it with `die()` and `.off("slide")` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you please simplify make your problem in fiddle?

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in the `slide` event if the value of `slider1` become greater the the max value and if so cancel the slide event by returnig false:

> Canceling the event will prevent the handle from moving and the handle
>   will continue to have its previous value.

Code:

```
$(function () {

    $("#slider1").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 30,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.value)
        }
    });

    $("#slider2").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 20,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.value + 10 > $("#slider1").slider("option", "max")) {
                return false
            }
            $("#slider1").slider("option", "value", ui.value + 10);
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9RFK2/

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying slider 2 value should not exceed the sider 1 value.

```
if (ui.value  > slider1.slider("option", "value")) {

            return false;
        }
```

Check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/smartyatwork/XSUgK/8/